# how to mute the output of the function hist()

Tags: matplotlib

I want to plot histogram of a image inside ipython notebook. When I run the cell with such command

```
axes[0].hist(simg.flatten(), bins=256)
```

it returns me both the plot and a long output array.

How to disable the output array? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign it to a dummy variable

```
_junk = axes[0].hist(simg.flatten(), bins=256)
```

Comment: Are there any other option?

Comment: Not really. You could wrap the method in a function that doesn't return anything, but that'd be silly and needlessly complex. @chuan